# How to run "rake resque:work QUEUE=*" when Rails server boots?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, resque

I have installed resque correctly, but to process all queues I need to run

```
rake resque:work QUEUE='*'
```

The problem is that I need to keep the terminal window opened, otherwise resque:work won't works.

Do you know a way to auto-run that rake command every time I run "rails server" ?

I'm on **Localhost**

**lib/tasks/resque.rake**

```
require 'resque/tasks'

task "resque:setup" => :environment do
    ENV['QUEUE'] = "*"
end
```

Comment: If you don't want to keep terminal with resque opened you can try to run resque in background [resque background](https://github.com/defunkt/resque#section_Workers_Running_in_the_background)

Comment: Thanks, it's Perfect! @AlexeySukhoviy Do you know how avoid to re-run this every time I restart my server?

Comment: Btw. If you run it in background, you can stop it by killing it as a process with kill -9 <pid> command. Where pid is a pid of resque process.
But for development purposes I recommend you not run resque in  background. As for me it is better to keep it lunched in another terminal and restart it only if I made some changes to code with which resque process operates.

Comment: maybe you could help me with this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24726631/how-to-start-resque-not-using-rails

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of calling the invoke function, you can use a gem like [foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman) that can invoke all the other tasks.
This is useful if you are looking to have a largely platform neutral solution and also while deploying into cloud.
Your Procfile can have the following contents:

```
web:    bundle exec thin start -p $PORT
worker: bundle exec rake resque:work QUEUE=*
clock:  bundle exec rake resque:scheduler
```

Source:[introduction to foreman](http://blog.daviddollar.org/2011/05/06/introducing-foreman.html).

Now to start the server, you just have to issue foreman start command which forks off child threads to perform individual work.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Answer from 2012! Seems that this works just for Rails 2!

Add an initializer in config/initializers with something like this:

```
Rake::Task["resque:work QUEUE='*'"].invoke
```

Not tested!

Comment: I know, I just specify for users landing here. :)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it is

```
ENV['QUEUE'] = "*"
Rake::Task["resque:work"].invoke
```