# How to start resque not using rails

Tags: ruby, resque, resque-scheduler

I am using ruby (not rails) and I have install resque gem. According to the manual, I should start the workers using the following command:

```
resque work
```

But this command doesn't start the workers at all (I have checked that resque file in bin/ and it doesn't accept 'work' at all).

Here is the output:

```
Usage: resque [options] COMMAND

Options:
    -r, --redis [HOST:PORT]          Redis connection string
    -N, --namespace [NAMESPACE]      Redis namespace
    -h, --help                       Show this message

Commands:
  remove WORKER   Removes a worker
  kill WORKER     Kills a worker
  list            Lists known workers
```

Answer (score 1):

Created rakefile with:

```
require "resque/tasks"
```

and run resque:

```
rake resque:work QUEUE=*
```